# In Excel, I want to search for individual words across a worksheet, and pull an associated number for each

Tags: excel, vba

So lets say I have two worksheets. One, the 'List' looks like this:

```
Anne
Barry
Ciaran
David
Eric
Freya
```

But a few thousand names long. Another worksheet, called Library, has this:

```
1
Anne
Ciaran
2
Anne
Barry
David
Freya
3
David
Eric
Freya
```

All the way down to 2000 or so.

Now, I wish to add extra data to the first List, adding the associated numbers with each name adjacent to them. So the output would be:

```
Anne    1    2 
Barry   2
Ciaran  1
David   2    3
Eric    3
Freya   2    3
```

Now, I'm hoping to have a VBA script that will produce the output from the data above. My first approach worked by cutting each segment from 'Library' as far as each number, and arranging them like so:

```
 1       2       3
 Anne    Anne    David
 Ciaran  Barry   Eric
         David   Freya
         Freya
```

Then ran through a simple script saying "If something in List matches any word in Library, then copy whatever is in Row 1 there."

However, re-arranging the data takes a long time for VBA do to. Is it possible to skip this step, and have a script work through the first list, saying "If any of these names matches something in the 'Library,' then copy the first number that appears in cells above it."

Is this the right approach? All feedback or suggestions welcome.

EDIT: This is the original script. I'll return and look at the other answers in greater detail shortly.

```
     Private Sub PrepareLibrary()
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim i As Long
  Dim n As Range 
  Dim x As Long
  Dim Library As Worksheet
  Dim List As Worksheet 'Defines Library and List as Worksheets, for referencing later
  Dim LastRow As Long
  Set Library = Sheets("Library")
  Set List = Sheets("List")
  i = 1
  x = 0
  LastRow = Library.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row

  Do While i <= LastRow
  Set Rng = Library.Range("A" & i)
  Set n = Library.Range("A1")

  If IsNumeric(Rng) = True Then  'If Rng is Numeric, then....
  x = x + 1 'Increases X, just like i as described earlier. However, in this script, X serves a different purpose
  Rng.Copy
  n.Offset(0, x).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'The amount of columns offset from the range    'n' defined here determined by the integer X
  i = i + 1
  ElseIf IsNumeric(Rng) = False Then
  Rng.Copy
  n.Offset(1, x).Insert Shift:=xlDown
  i = i + 1
  ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rng) = 0 Then
  i = i + 1

   End If
   Loop 'This script essentially re-arragnes the single column of keywords into multiple columns, one for each record
```

Comment: _re-arranging the data takes a long time for VBA do to_ - only if you do it badly. Post that code and we can help optimise it

Answer (score 1):

**edited**: to account for numbers greater then 9...

**edited2**: used array to speed things up

I'd go like follows

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
Dim cell As Range, lastCell As Range
Dim i As Long, iArr As Long, dataArr() As Long, nameCount As Long
Dim data As String

With Worksheets("Library")
    Set lastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
    With .Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
        For i = 1 To .Areas.Count - 1
            data = data & .Areas(i) & Join(Application.Transpose(Range(.Areas(i).Offset(1), .Areas(i + 1).Offset(-1))), .Areas(i))
        Next i
        data = data & .Areas(i) & Join(Application.Transpose(Range(.Areas(i).Offset(1), lastCell)), .Areas(i))
    End With
End With

With Worksheets("List").Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
    For Each cell In .Cells
        nameCount = (Len(data) - Len(Replace(data, cell.Value, ""))) / Len(cell.Value)
        ReDim dataArr(1 To nameCount) As Long

        i = InStr(data, cell)
        iArr = 0
        Do While i > 0
            iArr = iArr + 1
            dataArr(iArr) = GetNumber(Left(data, i - 1))
            i = InStr(i + 1, data, cell)
        Loop
        cell.Offset(, 1).Resize(, iArr).Value = dataArr

    Next cell
End With
End Sub

Function GetNumber(text) As Long
Dim i As Long
Do While IsNumeric(Mid(text, Len(text) - i, 1))
    i = i + 1
    If i = Len(text) Then Exit Do
Loop
GetNumber = Right(text, i)
End Function
```

Comment: Excellent. This seems like a good starting point. I'm getting a mismatch error for this line, however:

     data = data & .Areas(i)& Join(Application.Transpose(Range(.Areas(i).Offset(1), .Areas(i + 1).Offset(-1))), .Areas(i))

Can you tell me what the purpose of this line is, along with the Areas function? Thanks

Comment: that line builds up a string that concatenates each name with its preceeding number, resulting in something like _"1Anne1Ciaran2Anne2Barry2David2Freya3David3Eric3Freya"_ . `Areas` property of `Range` object returns a collection of all non adjacent multiple-area range (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff196243.aspx)). The given code works for data like those you posted. And which I replicated down to more than 4k rows in "Library" while maintaining 6 entries in "List". You may want to upload xlsx files (not xlsm!) with data sample that are giving you errors.

Answer (score 0):

If your desired output is something like

```
Anne 1 2
Barry 2
```

etc.
Then I think you can do this all in one step, i.e. a single cycle through Sheet 1 and then Sheet 2 and without any rearranging of data. The following is a rough outline:

1) Create a Collection object and then read in the list of names from the first sheet. For each name you read in, add a new collection object into your initial collection, using the name as the key.
So you'll end up with a collection of collections, with as many entries in the "master" collection as you have names.

2) Now cycle through your second sheet. For each name under a particular number, add that *number* to the collection in your master collection associated with that name (i.e. using the name as the key word to find the right collection within the master collection.

3) Finally cycle through the master collection and for each collection within it, cycle through the list of numbers and dump them in the appropriate cells.

The one problem with this approach is that you will get a list of numbers associated with each collection within the master collection - but you won't know the name associated with that collection! There are two solutions to that:
- apart from your master collection, keep another collection to which you just add names. Thus the n'th element of the master collection has key "Fred" (say) which you can't actually see. But the n'th element of your name collection contains the string "Fred".
- instead of using collections you could use a Dictionary associated with File Scripting. I believe here you can access the key value (though I have very little experience with this.

You will need to be careful to handle duplicate names correctly. (You can't have two "Fred"'s as keys to your master collection.

Comment: I'll give this a try. How do I create a collection object? Can you point me in a direction to learn more?

Thanks.

Comment: I have limited access right now but Just googling for "VBA Collection" should give you some good resources.

Comment: You can create a collection with Dim cln As New Collection OR in 2 lines as Dim cln As  Collection followed by Set clan = New Collection. In both cases then add items with cln.Add item:=itemtoad, key:= itemkey. When add a collection as the item to add, you will need to create a new collection each Tim you want to add an item.